# Create buttons from instances of a class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

So I am trying to build a restaurant menu.
I want to create buttons based on instances of class `Food`:

```
class Food:
    instances=[]
    def __init__(self,name,price):
        self.name=name
        self.price=price
        Food.instances.append(self)

    def __iter__(self):
        for item in Food.instances:
            yield item
    def get_name(self)
        return self.name
```

The code I have right now, works, but it also changes the `Food.instances` to button object, I want it to stay as `Food` objects, so I can call functions to get their name and price.

This is what I have right now:

```
def read_data():    #reads data from json file
    global data
    with open("restaurant\menu.json",'r') as f:
        data=json.loads(f.read())

def get_instances(json_data): #gets Food instances based on data loaded from json file
    for u in json_data:
        x=Food(**u)

def get_buttons(frame,list_aux): #makes buttons based on instances of Food class
    column=0
    rows=0
    for index,obj in enumerate(list_aux):
        if column<3:
            list_aux[index]=Button(frame,text=obj.get_name())
            list_aux[index].grid(row=rows,column=column)
            column+=1
        else:
            column=0
            rows+=1
            list_aux[index]=Button(frame,text=obj.get_name())
            list_aux[index].grid(row=rows,column=column)
            column+=1

read_data()
get_instances(data)
print(Food.instances)
list_aux=Food.instances #makes a copy of Food.instances to HOPEFULLY not mess up the class
root=Tk()
get_buttons(root,list_aux)
root.mainloop()
```

Before running `get_buttons()` function, when I print `Food.instances` I get: 
`[<__main__.Food object at 0x000001C0F0113E50>, <__main__.Food object at 0x000001C0EFD51960>, <__main__.Food object at 0x000001C0F0115A20>]`

After running the function, printing `list_aux` results in: 
`[<tkinter.Button object .!button>, <tkinter.Button object .!button2>, <tkinter.Button object .!button3>]`

But also, when print `Food.instances`, I get the same output and I lose all of the class methods written (`get_name()` and others I did not include here because are not relevant).

How can I keep creating those buttons, but not change `Food.instances`?
One workaround I have found is to modify the `get_instances()` function to:

```
def get_instances(json_data):
    Food.instances=[] #this is the line that is added
    for u in json_data:
        x=Food(**u)
```

So I can call it again after `get_buttons()` function, deleting those `tkinter.Button` objects, creating `Food` objects again, and I can use the class methods as before, but I feel like this is extremly inefficient. How can I fix this?

Comment: `list_aux=Food.instances` does **not** make a copy of `Food.instances`, it just gives it another name — this is why calling `get_instance()` changes it. Use `list_aux=Food.instances.copy()` to make a copy of the elements in the list. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: This works exactly how i wanted! Thank you!

Comment: @iCooKie, If it works, please answer your own question. Other people tend to see your question unanswered and see comments and leave. It wastes quite a lot of time. I myself came to this question twice to see it had been answered in comments

Comment: @Pycoder i posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i did was adding

```
list_aux = Food.instances.copy()
```

In the `get_buttons()` function
And removing it from the global space to not pollute it. This will create the buttons from the class, get all the information I wanted to get when creating the buttons, and still keep the original array in place so i can have access to the class methods